# HP MSR 30-10a Router - Route Traffic over Default Route

Tags: routing, router, hp, internet, 3com

We have a brand new HP MSR 30-10a Router. We have a fairly simple routing situation - we have two IP blocks, one which has a route out. We need things on the first block to go through the router, and out. I have an old Cisco 2801 router doing the job right now.

For our example -

IP Block 1: 
50.203.110.232/29, Router interface on this block is 50.203.110.237, route out is 50.203.110.233.

IP Block 2: 50.202.219.1/27, Router interface on this block at 50.202.219.20.

I have a static route created for:
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 50.203.110.233

The router seems to understand this. When on the CLI via serial cable, I can ping 8.8.8.8 and hear responses from Google DNS. Woo hoo!

The issue arrives when any client sits on the IP Block 2 side. I configured my client with a static IP of 50.202.219.15/27, default gateway 50.202.219.20. I can ping myself. I can ping the near side of the router (50.202.219.20), and I can ping the far side of the router (50.203.110.237. I cannot ping anything else in IP block 1, nor can I ping 8.8.8.8.

Here is my configuration file:

```
<HP>display current-configuration 
#
 version 5.20.106, Release 2507, Standard
#
 sysname HP
#
 domain default enable system
#
 dar p2p signature-file flash:/p2p_default.mtd
#
 port-security enable
#
 undo ip http enable
#
 password-recovery enable
#
vlan 1
#
domain system
 access-limit disable
 state active
 idle-cut disable
 self-service-url disable
#
user-group system
 group-attribute allow-guest
#
local-user admin
 password cipher $c$3$40gC1cxf/wIJNa1ufFPJsjKAof+QP5aV
 authorization-attribute level 3
 service-type telnet
#
cwmp
 undo cwmp enable
#
interface Aux0
 async mode flow
 link-protocol ppp
#
interface Cellular0/0
 async mode protocol
 link-protocol ppp
#
interface Ethernet0/0
 port link-mode route
 ip address 50.203.110.237 255.255.255.248
#
interface Ethernet0/1
 port link-mode route
 ip address 50.202.219.20 255.255.255.224
#
interface NULL0
#
 ip route-static 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 50.203.110.233 permanent
#
 load xml-configuration
#
 load tr069-configuration
#
user-interface tty 12
user-interface aux 0
user-interface vty 0 4
 authentication-mode scheme
#
```

My guess right now is there is some sort of "permission" needed to use the default route. The manuals haven't turned up a lot in this area that don't make the situation much more complicated (but maybe it needs to be more complicated?)

Background: we use HP switches, and I love the CLI. I bought HP thinking the command line interface would be similar, or at least speak the same language. Whoops!

I'd be happy to provide more information or perform any additional tests. Thanks in advance!

Update 1: The manual mentions routing rules. I hadn't previously added these (since our Cisco 2801 seems to route anything by default). I added:
ip ip-prefix 1 permit 0.0.0.0 0 less-equal 32
alas, still no dice.

Comment: No comments or answers so far, which could be confirming my suspicion that I should have bought a different router that is more common. Fingers crossed for an HP guru!

Answer (score 0):

I contacted HP Support. The word is - the configuration is great and the router will work set up like this! My pings aren't coming back because while my route out is correct, our incoming system doesn't have a route back (it goes to the live router which this one will be replacing).

To get this router to route traffic, I have two options:

- Call Comcast. Ask them to change the our route in
- Give this new router the same internal and external IP address (this is what I'll do).

Makes sense! A simple solution, and it's good to be affirmed that I set the router up correctly. I hope this helps someone else!

-Stead